# Grandes inteiros e primos

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma função que gere números primos e inteiros em tamanhos consideravelmente grandes?

Se não, como faze-lo usando JavaScript?

Comment: Você quer que alguém faça para você?

Comment: Você precisa mesmo gerar os números? Eles são conhecidos, eu montaria uma array com primos de uma tabela qualquer (como [esta](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/100000.txt)) e sortearia uma posição da array.

Comment: @Lucas nao, realmente nao sei trabalhar com geraçao de números deste tipo com JavaScript apenas php usando `gmp`, se tem ideia de como agradeceria a boa vontade.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim se eles fossem pré definidos seria fácil, mas o caso é realmente gerar números deste tipo, nao posso ter uma array pre moldada, estes serao usados para troca de chaves DH..

Comment: Por que você está implementando sua própria criptografia? E porquê você está fazendo cripto em JS?

Comment: @hugomg própria? Estou apenas usando idéias já existentes, comunicação entre dois pontos sem interferencia do servidor e terceiros.

Comment: Estou falando da implementação. Em geral é mais confiável usar bibliotecas existentes para cripto ao invés de programar tudo denovo você mesmo. E se sua cripto estiver rodando em um broser, tem o problema de um adversário interferir no código Javascript que o cliente recebe

Comment: @hugomg no lado do servidor eu tenho estes recursos, no lado do cliente nao tem tudo pronto na web, tem que fazer eu apenas interligo tudo a faço funcionar, ja revisei suficiente pro que eu quero, mas voltemos ao foco deste.

Comment: Você já tinha perguntado a mesma coisa sobre PHP e eu tinha dado a mesma sugestão, e outros usuários também (a pergunta não existe mais, você apagou). Não consigo entender por que gerar, os números primos são todos conhecidos (os que não são, não é um browser que vai conseguir calcular...). Não entendo por que você acha que eles seriam mais secretos se você calcular. Qualquer um com uma tabela de primos pode tentar um ataque *brute-force*, se é essa a sua preocupação.

Comment: Fora isso, lembre-se de que o maior inteiro permitido em JS é 9007199254740992. Você nunca conseguirá calcular primos maiores que isso. Portanto usar uma tabela de strings representando os números te permitiria usar primos ainda maiores.

Comment: @bfavaretto seria interessante ver a geraçao destes, mas vou seguir uma resposta que achei no SOen que explica um meio, obg, apagarei este em breve

Comment: @bfavaretto nao leve a mal, apenas nao quero me basear apenas em uma array que ainda por cima ficará exposta, seria algo como "toma os números pra vc tentar" mesmo sendo possivel fazer força bruta de outra forma, acho isso gambiarra.

Comment: Embora a pergunta tal como foi escrita dê margem para interpretação, eu pessoalmente [que tenho interesse em criptografia, apesar de não ser especialista] quando leio "primos muito grandes" já presumo se tratar de algo que vai além da representação em `int`, `long` ou `double`, algo que demande uma biblioteca de inteiros de precisão arbitrária. E a solução "padrão" para esse problema é sempre a mesma - gerar números aleatórios e testar se são provavelmente primos. O fato desses primos serem "conhecidos" não tem relevância no caso, pois o número deles é grande demais para testar de um por um.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma solução fazendo uso de [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge):

```
var bits = 1024;
forge.prime.generateProbablePrime(bits, function(err, num) {
    console.log('número primo aleatório', num.toString(16));
});
```

<sup>Crédito da solução para @dlongley [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039391/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

Comment: Interessante como isso funciona (está descrito na resposta do SOEN que você indicou). Ele gera um candidato a primo de maneira eficiente, e depois testa se é primo mesmo. Se não for, tenta outro candidato. E essa biblioteca forge parece ser exatamente o que o AP precisa para resolver o problema maior dele (que é de criptografia).

Comment: Adorei esta, estou tentando extrair apenas esta funçao com suas dependencias mas nao consigo, tem sugestao?

Answer (score 8):

Eu já [insisti o suficiente nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57537/grandes-inteiros-e-primos-javascript/57551#comment118630_57537) para você usar uma tabela de primos pré-definidos. Gerar primos em JavaScript não é nada eficiente, especialmente se você só precisa sortear um. Se você precisa de números com vários dígitos então, vai ser **bem** lento.

Segue uma adaptação da implementação do [Crivo de Eratóstenes](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes) [postada pelo usuário Guffa no site Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/code-for-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-javascript):

```js
function primosAte(n) {
  var i, j;
  var prime = new Array(n);
  for (i = 2; i < n ; i++) prime[i] = true;
  
  for (i = 2; i * i < n ; i++) {
    if (prime[i]) {
      for (j = 0; i * i + i * j < n ; j++) {
        prime[i * i + i * j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  var primes = [];
  for (i = 2 ; i < n ; i++) {
    if (prime[i]){
      primes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}
 
var primos = primosAte(1000);
document.body.innerHTML = primos.toString(', ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma das bibliotecas nessa página para resolver o seu problema:

- http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

## -- Transcrição traduzida de uma parte --

A API da biblioteca jsbn lembra bastante as classes `java.math.BigInteger` do Java. Por exemplo:

```
x = new BigInteger("abcd1234", 16);
y = new BigInteger("beef", 16);
z = x.mod(y);
alert(z.toString(16));
```

vai imprimir `b60c`.

### Core Library

- [jsbn.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/jsbn.js) - implmentação básica de `BigInteger`, o suficiente para criptografia RSA e não muito mais.
- [jsbn2.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/jsbn2.js) - o resto da biblioteca, incluindo a maioria dos métodos públicos de `BigInteger`.

### RSA

- [rsa.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa.js) - implementação da criptografia RSA, não requer jsbn2.js.
- [rsa2.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa2.js) - resto do algoritmo RSA, incluindo decriptação e geração de chave.

### ECC

- [ec.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/ec.js) - matemática de curvas elípticas, depende de jsbn.js e jsbn2.js
- [sec.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/sec.js) - parâmetros padrão de curvas elípticas

### Utilities

- [rng.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rng.js) - interface coletora de entropia rudimentar RNG, requer um backend PRNG para definir prng_newstate().
- [prng4.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/prng4.js) - PRNG backend baseado em ARC4 para rng.js, bem pequeno.
- [base64.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/base64.js) - rotinas de codificação e decodificação de Base64.
- [sha1.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/sha1.js) - função hash SHA-1, só é necessária para demo IBE.

**-- Fim da transcrição --**

## Algoritmos para gerar primos muito grandes

Achei uma [implementação de um algoritmo em python](http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/)

Comment: perdao, nao entendi o contexto de ligaçao pergunta-resposta.

Comment: Estas são bibliotecas para usar números grandes em JavaScript. Como há uma parte da biblioteca que gera chaves, então você deve achar a parte que gera números primos bem grandes lá.

Comment: Editei com uma implementação em Python, mas não sei se vou ter tempo para traduzir pra JavaScript... é muito código.

Comment: Nao entendo patavilhas de python mas muito obrigado!

Comment: @user3163662 Esse último algoritmo citado é para encontrar números que são *garantidamente* primos. Antigamente, enquanto esse problema ainda estava em aberto, só se podia determinar [em tempo hábil] se um número era *provavelmente* primo, e isso continuou sendo "bom o bastante" para muitas aplicações práticas (mesmo depois da descoberta de um algoritmo polinomial que dá uma resposta exata). Como você não cita na pergunta qual o propósito desses primos, não tenho como dizer se no seu caso é ou não é importante essa garantia (provavelmente não é).

Comment: Eu estou tentando traduzir o código... mesmo que não seja importante para esta questão, parece que pode ser algo útil.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a intençao destes primos é fazer a troca DH, tentei extrair a api que gera isso da biblioteca forge mas nao obtive exito, vc tem uma soluçao aparente?

Comment: @mgibsonbr nao é necessario para mim números extremamente grandes, só que sejam aptos para uso no DH normal,

Comment: @user3163662 Conheço muito pouco de Diffie-Hellman (exceto a teoria), mas até onde eu saiba os primos usados *precisam* ser grandes, enormes até, mas não sei te dizer se eles precisam ou não ser secretos. Sei que pelo menos um de seus parâmetros não é secreto, há inclusive [uma lista recomendada desses parâmetros](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3526). De todo modo, como esse assunto anda muito popular ultimamente (você é a 3ª ou 4ª pessoa que aparece com dúvidas desse tipo), estou escrevendo um par pergunta-resposta para ajudar a esclarecer alguns dos detalhes mais finos do DH em JavaScript.

Comment: @mgibsonbr poisé, minha dúvida de como gerar números primos continua 'pendente'

Comment: @user3163662 A resposta do Zuul não te atende? Nem alguma das bibliotecas mencionadas nesta resposta? O processo básico é esse mesmo: gere números aleatórios e faça-os passar por um teste de primalidade (exato ou probabilístico). Implementar isso à mão é osso (estudei na faculdade, mas como exercício somente), melhor procurar uma implementação já pronta.

Comment: @user3163662 Dei um exemplo completo de DH [nessa pergunta-resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57588/215), usando WebCrypto (*ainda* não é 100% *cross-browsers* mas está quase lá), ou seja, sem a necessidade de nenhuma biblioteca externa. Se for pra usar na prática (e não só para estudo), recomendo fortemente que use isso em vez de fazer à mão.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Ainda que não seja útil *para o AP*, seria útil pra pergunta sim, se você estiver mesmo disposto a traduzir o código (o que não deve ser tarefa fácil...). Só não te dei +1 ainda pois você só citou um monte de bibliotecas de *bignum*, o que por si só não responde ao que foi perguntado...

Answer (score -1):

`function primosAte(n) {
    var i, j;
    var prime = new Array(n);
    for (i = 2; i < n ; i++) prime[i] = true;`

```
for (i = 2; i * i < n ; i++) {
if (prime[i]) {
  for (j = 0; i * i + i * j < n ; j++) {
    prime[i * i + i * j] = false;
  }
}
}
var primes = [];
for (i = 2 ; i < n ; i++) {
  if (prime[i]){
  primes.push(i);
}
}
return primes;
```

}

var primos = 
   primosAte(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
   document.body.innerHTML = primos.toString(', ');