# Função para checar se número é primo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matemática

Em PHP usaria:

```
for($i = 3; $i <= ceil(sqrt($num)); $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }
```

Qual a função para fazer a verificação usando JS?

Comment: Se você pretende usar isso no Diffie-Hellman, como [comentado em uma outra pergunta recente sua](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57537/grandes-inteiros-e-primos#comment118608_57537), **mencione isso na pergunta!** Da forma como está, parece um exercício simples, e as respostas recebidas provavelmente serão inúteis para você (não dá pra testar números muito grandes usando esse algoritmo).

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o problema? Não esqueça de aceitar alguma se for o caso. Se não resolveu você pode colocar recompensa.

Answer (score 11):

Se o número for relativamente pequeno, dá pra fazer essa verificação simplesmente testando se ele possui divisores, como [sugerido por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57584/215). Caso contrário, essa solução vai ficando cada vez mais cara, até o ponto de se tornar impraticável (mesmo para números diretamente representáveis em JavaScript, sem o uso de qualquer biblioteca externa).

```js
    function isPrime(number) {
        var start = 2;
        while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
            if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
        }
        return number > 1;
    }

var inicio = new Date();
document.body.innerHTML += 1125899839733757 + " " + isPrime(1125899839733757) + " " + (new Date() - inicio) + "ms<br/>";
inicio = new Date();
document.body.innerHTML += 1125899839733759 + " " + isPrime(1125899839733759) + " " + (new Date() - inicio) + "ms<br/>";
```

Para números maiores, existe o [Teste AKS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_primalidade_AKS) - capaz de retornar "sim" ou "não" com 100% de certeza e em tempo polinomial em relação ao tamanho do número - mas o mais comum em usos práticos é o [Teste de Miller-Rabin](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_primalidade_de_Miller-Rabin), um [algoritmo probabilístico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_probabil%C3%ADstico) que retorna "não" com 100% de certeza ou "sim" com X% de certeza, sendo X configurável (e cujo tempo de execução depende o X escolhido, tendendo para o infinito).

Há [um exemplo de implementação desse algoritmo em JavaScript](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#JavaScript) no site rosettacode (bem como implementações em várias outras linguagens). Note que essa implementação é **bastante** ingênua, de modo que ela falha até para números muito pequenos (a potência módulo n é implementada potência primeiro, módulo depois...) .

```js
function probablyPrime(n, k) {
 if (n === 2 || n === 3)
  return true;
 if (n % 2 === 0 || n < 2)
  return false;
 
 // Write (n - 1) as 2^s * d
 var s = 0, d = n - 1;
 while (d % 2 === 0) {
  d /= 2;
  ++s;
 }
 
 WitnessLoop: do {
  // A base between 2 and n - 2
  var x = Math.pow(2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - 3)), d) % n;
 
  if (x === 1 || x === n - 1)
   continue;
 
  for (var i = s - 1; i--;) {
   x = x * x % n;
   if (x === 1)
    return false;
   if (x === n - 1)
    continue WitnessLoop;
  }
 
  return false;
 } while (--k);
 
 return true;
}

document.body.innerHTML += probablyPrime(13, 10); // 99.999905% de chance de estar correto
```

E de todo modo, se você precisar de uma implementação dessas você *provavelmente* também precisará de uma biblioteca de inteiros de precisão arbitrária (*bigint*) - uma vez que o tipo `Number` de JavaScript só dá suporte a ponto flutuante de 64 bits. Aqui tem [um exemplo de implementação com essa característica](https://www.npmjs.com/package/miller-rabin), para o node.js (mas provavelmente adaptável para o *browser* também).

Answer (score 6):

De acordo com essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390131/221800) dá para fazer assim:

```js
function isPrime(number) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    return number > 1;
}
console.log(isPrime(13));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/IsPrime.js).

Answer (score 5):

Eu fiz um código um pouco diferente, se quiserem dar uma olhada.

```js
let number = 3;
let primo = "O número " + number + " é primo";
let noPrimo = "O número " + number + " não é primo";
let result = noPrimo;

for (i = 2; i < number; i++) {
 result = primo;

 if (number % i == 0) {
  result = noPrimo;
  break;  
 }
}

if (number == 2) {
 result = primo;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok ok ok, é quase a mesma coisa: em **bash**, e com batota!

```
$ eprimo () { curl -s http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/100000.txt | 
              grep -q -w $1 && echo "Sim" || echo "Não"; }

$ eprimo 33
Não
```

... mas só dá resposta se o argumento for menor que 1_299_827 e se tivermos
um sistema operativo (i.e. curl, grep e coisas do género).

---

\cite{@bfavaretto, [comentário  longinquo a uma pergunta do mesmo PO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57537/grandes-inteiros-e-primos#comment118608_57537)}

**Update 1**

Esta resposta foi votada negativamente (pelo menos até -4) provavelmente
por só calcular se o número é primo até 1_299_827.

Na continuação das repostas tipo "soluções alternativas com batota", proponho o uso 
do comando unix `primes` que dá a sequência de números primos num intervalo, ou a sequência de primos
a partir de um número.

Um número é primo se o primeiro primo a seguir a ele (`primes N | head -1`)for 
ele próprio! :)

Portanto:

```
$ perl -E '$n=shift; say((`primes $n|head -1`== $n)? "sim":"não")' 4294967231
sim
```

Comment: Vale bem a pena ser downvoted para poder falar de pequenas variantes que acho curiosas! :)

Comment: No update 1 recorreu-se a Perl para evitar graçolas de um conhecido moderador, envolvendo a shell anteriormente usada (...your answer was bashed) :).