# Verificar se o número é primo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bom, eu fiz esse código para mostrar se o número do textbox é primo, se for aparecer uma mensagem no parágrafo com id mensagem. Mas não funciona, se alguém podesse me dizer onde estou errando. Ficaria grato.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   function primo(num) {
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i === 0) return false;
    return num !== 1;
    var resl = "O número" + primo(num) + "é primo";
 document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = resl;
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>
 <input type="text" id='name'/>
 </p>
<input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar" onclick = "primo(num)"/>
<p id="mensagem"></p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Visualmente podes experimentar  `onclick=primo(this.value)` e tem código depois do `return`.

Comment: na verdade muita coisa está errada aí.

Comment: muita coisa mesmo,  porque se utilizar `onclick=primo(this.value)` voce estaria pegando o valor do botao... e depois e um `return` o código é ignorado...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fiz bem rápido aqui, retirando o código que estava depois o return, que era ignorado. Coloquei na outra funcao na qual chama a funçao principal sua. Está bem básico, dá para melhorar...

**EDIT**

Adicionei algumas verificações, se for numero e se é diferente se 1...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function primo(num) {
    // verifica se o numero digitado é "1", que não é primo
     if(num!=1){
      for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
      return num !== 1;
    }
    }

    function verificaPrimo() {
      var num = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var resl="";
      // verifica se é número
     if(!isNaN(num)){
      // verifica se é primo
      if (primo(num)) {
       resl = "O número " + (num) + " é primo";
        
      } else {
       resl = "O número " + (num) + " nao éprimo";
      }
      document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = resl;
    }

else{
 document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "Vish, nem número é";
}
}
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id='name' />
  </p>
  <input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar" onclick="verificaPrimo()" />
  <p id="mensagem"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: se digitar uma letra retorna primo

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, sim. Inclusive se digitar o "1" ... Fiz apenas o exemplo para não fugir muito do código dele

Comment: Tranquilo, mas poderia melhorar!!! Comunidade ficaria feliz.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Editei :)

Comment: blz, dando upvote

Comment: o Vish foi divertido, rs  :)

Comment: Tá congelando para primos grandes ex: 16148168401

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo aqui deu... E nao é primo. Congelando como?

Comment: no meu é primo 16148168401 uai, aqui tá congelando sim, dá uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198233/porque-um-script-congela-o-navegador-e-o-outro-n%C3%A3o-se-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-loops-%C3%A9-o-mesm

Comment: precisamos de uma terceira opinião  http://www.onlineconversion.com/prime.htm

Answer (score 6):

Faça assim:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>
 <input type="text" id='name'/>
 </p>
<input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar">
<p id="mensagem"></p>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
   function isPrime(num) {
      for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false;
      return num !== 1;
    }
    // campos texto e botao
    var el = document.getElementById('name'), btn = document.getElementById('verificarvalor');
    // esperar click sobre o botao
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // verificar se o valor digitado é um numero
        if(!isNaN(el.value)){
            if(isPrime(el.value)){
                alert(el.value + ' é primo');
            } else {
                alert(el.value + ' nao é primo');
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
   function isPrime(num) {
   for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
  if(num % i === 0) return false;
   return num !== 1;
 }
 // campos texto e botao
 var el = document.getElementById('name'), btn = document.getElementById('verificarvalor');
 // esperar click sobre o botao
 btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // verificar se o valor digitado é um numero
  if(el.value && !isNaN(el.value)){
   if(isPrime(el.value)){
    alert(el.value + ' é primo');
   } else {
    alert(el.value + ' nao é primo');
   }
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>
 <input type="text" id='name'/>
 </p>
<input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar">
<p id="mensagem"></p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Em qualquer linguagem de programação *(pelo menos das que conheço)* nenhum código depois do `return` é executado. Além disso, no seu código as atribuições estavam mal feitas, declarar `primo(num)` para o botão, seria inválido, porque para já não existe *num* no contexto dado, e o botão não possui qualquer valor. Outra coisa é a colocação da tag `script`, é sempre preferível que se coloque logo após o conjunto que o vai executar, normalmente junto a tag `</body>`.

Em alternativa, caso queiras algo bem mais simples, podes fazer assim:

```
<input type="text" id='name'/>
</p>
<input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar" onclick="primo()">
<p id="mensagem"></p>
</div>
```

E o código *javascript*:

```
function primo(){
    var el = document.getElementById('name'), msg = document.getElementById('mensagem');
    if(el.value && !isNaN(el.value)){
        if((el.value % 2) === 1){
            msg.innerHTML = "Numero: " + el.value + " e primo";
        } else {
            msg.innerHTML = "Numero: " + el.value + " nao e primo";
        }
    }   
}
```

Caso prefiras algo ainda mais simples, a solução é substituir esta expressão dentro do if:

```
(el.value % 2) === 1
```

Por esta aqui:

```
el.value & 1
```

> [SOpt - Função para checar se numero é primo em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57579/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-checar-se-n%C3%BAmero-%C3%A9-primo-em-javascript)

Comment: Então, sou estudante ainda. Estou aprendendo rss. Isso aí foi um exercício passado pelo meu professor. E o seu código só não me ajudou tanto pq vc colocou addEventListener e o professor só quer que a gente use o que ele ensinou. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelas dicas.

Comment: @Uondaime se tiver tempo edito para algo bem mais simples de se entender.

Comment: Ah, ficarei muito grato. Abraço!

Comment: @Uondaime aí tens, algo relativamente mais simples.

Comment: "campo vazio" está retornando primo. Este é o comportamento esperado mesmo no javascript?

Comment: @diegofm desculpa ?

Comment: Eu abri o snippet e cliquei em "calcular" com o campo sem nada, e retornou "é primo". É esse o comportamento esperado mesmo?

Comment: @diegofm provavelmente por causa das condições que aí estão, removi o "campo vazio", mas continua a validar 0, apesar de ser neutro.

Answer (score 4):

**FONTE** [StudyMaths.co.uk](http://studymaths.co.uk/topics/checkIfPrime.php)

> Filtro para aceitar somente números, e quantidade de algarismos digitados no input igual a 12
>
> `maxlength="12"` **para evitar travamento do navegador**.

```js
function primo() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    if (!isNaN(number)) {
       if (isPrime(number)) {
          document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = number + " É primo!";
       }
       else {
         document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = number + " Não é primo.";
       }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "Só aceita números, volta pra escola";
    }
}

function isPrime(n) {

   if (n < 2) {return false}
        if (n != Math.round(n)) {return false}
           var isPrime = true;

           for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
               if (n % i == 0) {return false;}
            }

    return isPrime;
 }
```

```html
<input id="number" value="0" maxlength="12" size="8" onclick="this.select()" />
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="primo()" />
<p id="mensagem"> </p>
```

Exemplos de números primos: 104729 - 20173 - 1117111 - 777767777 - 16148168401

[Lista dos primeiros 10000 números primos](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Teoria_de_n%C3%BAmeros/10000_primos)

> **Para evitar o congelamento do seu navegador, limitei o input a 12 digitos**

[Porque um script congela o navegador e o outro não se o número de loops é o mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198233/porque-um-script-congela-o-navegador-e-o-outro-n%C3%A3o-se-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-loops-%C3%A9-o-mesm).