# Porque um script congela o navegador e o outro não se o número de loops é o mesmo?

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 scripts **A** e **B**.

Testando se um número é primo no script A o navegador congela com números primos grandes - 9 algarismos - (ex: 777767777 ).

Fiz teste no Chrome e IE, os dois navegadores congelaram.

No script B esse mesmo número primo não congela os navegadores, aliás aceita números com mais algarismos.

**Script A** congela

```js
function primo(num) {
    // verifica se o numero digitado é "1", que não é primo
    if(num!=1) {
        for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if (num % i == 0) return false;
         return num !== 1;
    }
}

function verificaPrimo() {
    var num = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var resl="";
    // verifica se é número
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        // verifica se é primo
        if (primo(num)) {
           resl = "O número " + (num) + " é primo";
        } else {
            resl = "O número " + (num) + " nao éprimo";
        }
        document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = resl;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "Vish, nem número é";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='name' />
<input type="button" name="botão" id="verificarvalor" value="Verificar" onclick="verificaPrimo()" />
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

**Script B**

```js
function primo() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    if (!isNaN(number)) {
        if (isPrime(number)) {
            document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = number + " É primo!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = number + " Não é primo.";
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "Só aceita números, volta pra escola";
    }
}

function isPrime(n) {
    if (n < 2) {return false}
        if (n != Math.round(n)) return false;
        var isPrime = true;
        for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return isPrime;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" value="0" maxlength="12" size="8" onclick="this.select()" />
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="primo()" />
<p id="mensagem"> </p>
```

Comment: Não sei de onde tirou que eles executam a mesma quantidade de iterações. Há uma diferença exponencial. Um roda quase 1 bilhão de vezes e o outro menos de 30 mil vezes. Curiosamente o segundo é menos eficiente no caso de não ser primo já que ele continua iterando mesmo já sabendo a resposta.

Comment: @bigown a quantidade de iterações é diferente, mas a quantidade de laços é realmente igual. Cada algoritmo só tem um `for` ;)

Comment: @Renan é verdade, eu interpretei *loops* como interações :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo troque `isPrime = false;` por `return false;`

Comment: @bigown previ o comentário do amigo Renan :) rs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL; DR**: o navegador "congela" porque ele tem muitos mais cálculos para fazer no algoritmo **A**.

É uma questão de matemática.

Os dois códigos são parecidos. A diferença principal está na quantidade de iterações nos laços:

```
// A
for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if (num % i == 0) return false;
```

e

```
// B
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        isPrime = false
    }
}
```

A propósito, isso poderia ser melhorado se você já guardasse o valor de `Math.sqrt(n)` em uma variável.

`Math.sqrt(n)` retorna a raiz quadrada de `n`. Isso significa que, para determinado número `n`, o laço do algoritmo **A** executará `n` vezes - mas o laço do algoritmo **B** executará `n^(1/2)` vezes, arredondado para o maior inteiro menor que a raiz. A diferença na quantidade de execuções é enorme. Veja a curva da função raiz quadrada:

[image: Função raiz]

No caso em que `n` é igual a mil, o algoritmo **A** executa mil vezes. Já o algoritmo **B** executa apenas trinta vezes. A diferença cresce conforme `n` cresce: para `n` igual a um milhão, o algoritmo **A** executa um milhão de vezes enquanto **B** executa apenas mil vezes.

Isso funciona para descobrir se um número é primo, pois todo número ímpar que não é primo possui um divisor menor que sua própria raiz quadrada. Isso diminui a quantidade de divisões que você precisa testar para descartar a hipótese de um número ser primo.

Comment: Eu só melhoraria ainda botando um `return` no lugar da *flag*, não só pq é mais rápido, mas tb pq **quase** toda vez que tem uma *flag* tem algo errado no código, pelo menos em estilo.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo variáveis booleanas (essas que recebem os valores `true` ou `false`), quando você usa pra controlar o comportamento do script.