# Como fazer o valor aparecer clicando em qualquer canto da página JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bom, estou com um exercício de javascript que tenho que fazer aparecer se o valor de um número é primo ou não. Porém não estou conseguindo, pois o professor quer que o valor apareça quando clicarmos em qualquer canto da página no parágrafo com id="mensagem". É para usar o onchange, mas não consegui. Abaixo o código.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function primo(num) {
    // verifica se o numero digitado é "1", que não é primo
     if(num!=1){
      for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
      return num !== 1;
    }
    }

    function verificarPrimo() {
      var num = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var resl="";
      // verifica se é número
     if(!isNaN(num)){
      // verifica se é primo
      if (primo(num)) {
       resl = "O número ".fontcolor("blue") + (num).fontcolor("blue") + " é primo".fontcolor("blue");
        
      } 
       else {
       resl = "O número ".fontcolor("red") + (num).fontcolor("red") + " não é primo".fontcolor("red");
      }


      document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = resl;
    }


else{
 document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML;
}

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="logogedc.png" width="500px" height="130px" 
 onMouseOver="this.src='logogedc2.png'"
 onMouseOut="this.src='logogedc.png'">
  <p>
   Digite um número:<input type="text" id="name" onfocus="this.value='';"  /><br><br>
    Clique fora para descobrir se o número é primo ou não.
  </p>
  <div>
  <p id="mensagem"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite,
para chamar o **onchange** basta fazer o segunte na tag **input** ***onchange="verificarPrimo(this.value)"***.
Podes continuar usando sua função para verificar se o número é primo, porém para este exemplo eu usei a função do link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57597/73009 pois achei mais completa.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function probablyPrime(n, k) {
  if (n === 2 || n === 3)
   return true;
  if (n % 2 === 0 || n < 2)
   return false;
  
  // Write (n - 1) as 2^s * d
  var s = 0, d = n - 1;
  while (d % 2 === 0) {
   d /= 2;
   ++s;
  }
  
  WitnessLoop: do {
   // A base between 2 and n - 2
   var x = Math.pow(2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - 3)), d) % n;
  
   if (x === 1 || x === n - 1)
    continue;
  
   for (var i = s - 1; i--;) {
    x = x * x % n;
    if (x === 1)
     return false;
    if (x === n - 1)
     continue WitnessLoop;
   }
  
   return false;
  } while (--k);
  
  return true;
 }
 
 function verificarPrimo(valor) {
  var numeroPrimo = probablyPrime(valor, 10);
  document.getElementById("mensagem").style.color = (numeroPrimo ? "blue" : "red");
  document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "O número " + valor + (numeroPrimo ? "" : " não") + " é primo";
 }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="logogedc.png" width="500px" height="130px" 
 onMouseOver="this.src='logogedc2.png'"
 onMouseOut="this.src='logogedc.png'">
  <p>
   Digite um número:<input type="text" id="name" onfocus="this.value='';" onchange="verificarPrimo(this.value)" /><br><br>
    Clique fora para descobrir se o número é primo ou não.
  </p>
  <div>
  <p id="mensagem"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Na verdade, foi um erro meu. Não fechei a última chave. Obrigado!