# Os 100 primeiros números primos

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Criei um código para imprimir na tela os 100 primeiros números primos, porém a tela fica em branco.

Sei que provavelmente não estou fazendo da melhor forma, gostaria da correção desse e a melhor forma de resolver o problema, se possível.

```
var dividendo, div, soma;
for(dividendo=1;(dividendo>0)&&(dividendo<100);dividendo++){
    div=1;
    soma=0;
    while(dividendo>=div){
        if((dividendo/div==1)||(dividendo/div==dividendo)){
            soma=soma+1;
            if((soma=1)||(soma=2)){
                document.write(dividendo);
            }
            div++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você percebeu que na primeira linha do seu `for`você iguala `div` a 1 e sempre que o laço executa de novo ele iguala de novo? div vai ser 1 eternamente assim.
Fora isso, o que seria `(dividendo/div==1)` ? Outra coisa: `document.write` é diferente de `console.log`, o primeiro comando vai deixar sua tela toda branca e escrever o que você disse. Se você executar de novo, vai apagar o antigo e substituir o novo valor. Use `console.log()` para ver todos os números no console.

Comment: Elabore melhor o que significa "não está funcionando". Tem alguma mensagem de erro? Não mostra nada? Entra em loop infinito?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Função para checar se número é primo em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57579/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-checar-se-n%c3%bamero-%c3%a9-primo-em-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários problemas nesta lógica que não sei nem por onde começar. Além do código estar complexo demais. Divida o problema para entender mais fácil.

A lógica básica é contar até 99 (conforme estava no código) para testar todos os números que deseja, isso é uma coisa. A lógica que testa se é primo ou não é outra coisa e o ideal já é ser uma função, e assim ainda evita usar *flags* que seriam necessárias sem a separação. Comecei pelo 2 porque 1 sabidamente não é primo.

No teste você tem que testar a partir do 2 porque divisível por 1 tudo é. E vai até o número anterior ao que está testando, todo número é divisível por ele mesmo, sendo primo ou não.

Quem não é primo é aquele que é divisível por algum outro número que não seja só 1 ou ele mesmo. Então qualquer situação que o resto da divisão seja igual a zero já sabemos que ele não é primo e nem precisamos mais continuar verificando o resto.

Se passar por toda verificação e nada for divisível aí sim ele é primo.

```js
function ehPrimo(i) {
    for (var divisor = 2; divisor < i; divisor++) if (i % divisor == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) if (ehPrimo(i)) document.write(i + '\n');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/IsPrime2.js).